# How do I setup reverse proxy in local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have to implement reverse proxy setup in my local system. I have two website and in first website i have content and second website have empty forlder, I have one website example - www.nawaz-data.com and it has main content. and I have another website example - www.nawaz-proxy.com which is empty folder .

Requirement :

Need how do i setup for reverse proxy. When i request to www.nawaz-proxy.com than it should be redirect to www.nawaz-data.com where i have actual website content. I have tried to setup inbound and outbound rule but unable to get result it shows : HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden as this domain has no content, i want to redirect this url to another url where content has stored.

I have installed IIS windows 10
I have installed URL Rewrite
I have installed Application Request Routing Cache - in that I have enable proxy setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below steps to add the reverse proxy rules.

1.Open the IIS mangement console, locate the right web site and click the url rewrite

[image]

2.Click the Add rule and select reverse proxy.

[image]

3.Add the servername op IP in below window, for example: www.nawaz-data.com. Notice: you should make sure your server could access the "www.nawaz-data.com" directly by using brower. If you couldn't access it ,you should use server's ip address directly.

[image]